# How do I apply a function designed for one number to an entire dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wrote a function that works as follows: `matrix[24787][24788] = generate_value(source, 24787, 24788)`

I want to generalize this to `matrix = generate_value(source, <array of indices>, <array of columns>)` and have the entire matrix filled in.  How can I do this, short of writing two loops?

Edit: Here is `generate_value` -

```
def generate_value(source, id_a, id_b):
  intersection = pd.merge(source.get_group(id_a), source.get_group(id_b), how='outer', on='merge_field')
  intersection.val_x.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
  intersection.val_y.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
  intersection.total_value_differences = abs(intersection.val_x - intersection.val_y)
  return sum(intersection.total_value_differences)
```

I can rewrite it if necessary.

Comment: This depends heavily on how `generate_value` is written. In the easiest case, it'll just work, due to how NumPy handles operations like `array + other_array`. In nastier cases, you might be stuck slapping `numpy.vectorize` on your function and getting essentially the same performance as two Python loops.

Comment: It did not work on its own, and `numpy.vectorize` vectorizes the `source` dataframe even if I explicitly exclude it as follows: `newfunc = numpy.vectorize(generate_value, excluded=['source'])`.  I've posted the source code for `generate_value` in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks impossible for this function in pandas at the moment.